# R How to generate unique list outputs using if statements in a for loop?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a filelist where files going into the for loop have different numbers of columns.  I want to generate a subset of each input file where the time variable (column) is >800 and where the number of the input file is also part of the output list.

Because of the different columns numbers (6,7,8, or 9), I was able to use a version of the code (if statements) below to output lists for one file at a time.  But when I try to loop it and change the file names I get:

`Error in subset[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

```
for (i in 1:n)
    {currentfile<- filelist[i]
    a=read.csv(currentfile, header=F)
    b=a[3:1000]
    mat-as.matrix(b)
    mat2.df<-as.data.frame(mat2)
    if (ncol(mat2.df) == 6) subset6[[i]]<-subset[[i]](mat2.df, time>800)
    if (ncol(mat2.df) == 7) subset7[[i]]<-subset[[i]](mat2.df, time>800)
    if (ncol(mat2.df) == 8) subset8[[i]]<-subset[[i]](mat2.df, time>800)
    if (ncol(mat2.df) == 9) subset9[[i]]<-subset[[i]](mat2.df, time>800)'
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you want 4 separate lists of files? The loop is also assigning values to list objects subset6, subset7, subset8, and subset9. You would have to create them first, perhaps with the following command:

```
subset6 = list()
```

Personally, I don't think any of it is necessary. Why not just initialize a list as

```
subsets = list()
```

Then, within your loop, you can write

```
subsets[[i]] = subset(mat2.df, time>800)
```

If you want separate lists, you have another problem with the fact that you will want separate counters to index each list. So, you will want an `i6`, `i7`, `i8`, and `i9` for your each individual list.

On a smaller note, I can't be sure about the typos in the earlier part of your code. It's hard to troubleshoot error messages attributed to a later set of conditional statements if the earlier statements which handled the pre-formatting of your input might have errors.

```
b= a[3:1000] 
mat-as.matrix(b)
```

These should probably read:

```
b <- a[3:1000, ]
mat2 <- as.matrix(b)
```

and `read.csv` has a `skip` option you could use.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you are trying to apply an index ("subset") to a function ("object of type closure").

The error message is a bit more confusing considering that the function you are trying to subset is called `subset`.

The offending portions are the parts:  `subset[[i]](mat2.df. . .`

Move those `[[i]]` to the end of the parenthesis and you should be fine.

```
   subset(mat2.df, time>800)[[i]]
```

---

Separate from that issue, you might want to revisit your `for` loop.
For example, what is the motivation behind these lines?  And are they accomplishing their intended purpose?

```
     mat - as.matrix(b)
     mat2.df <- as.data.frame(mat2)
```

Comment: I tried moving the [[i]] but now get an error saying: object 'subset6' not found.

As for the data frame, it does have a purpose outside the scope of this question.  Thanks for the response.